# Set text in a textview of another applicaton

Tags: android, textview

I have an android application(first one) which starts another app(second one). How do i set text in a textview of another applicaton( i.e second one) using data sent from the first app???
P.S-I dont have control over the second app . It is not created by me

Comment: _It is not created by me_.I don't think you can do anything about that then.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can do.

You said yourself `I don't have control over the second app`.

**This is the problem**

Lets say someone wanted to pass data to your app.

Would you know what to do with it, how to handle it and why he put it there?

No, you'd never know that and that's a sure-fire way to have malware problems.

*Hence Google hasn't and probably never will include this functionality*

Comment: fine leave the app thing. wat if i wanted to set text in a textview of a web page tat i open from my app? is there a way to do tat?

Comment: Sorry. If your starting the browser that's another 3rd party app. On the other hand if you use a `WebView` you just might be able to do something but I wouldn't think so. Then again it could be possible

Comment: If i use a webview is possible to do?? if so how?

Comment: As I said it might be possible. Check out WebViews here http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html